# linux + Backup & Restore tool for Blade IBM/HP machines

Tags: linux, backup, restore, blade

OUR target  - Backup & restore tool that can be put on a PXE server so that a client can be booted via network:

I hope that I ask the right question, there are allot of backup & restore tools so I little confused and I want to fit the backup & restore tool for blade HW ( to support network blade drivers )

In my company we have blade machine – as HS21 type .

On all blade machine we install red-hat Linux OS ( version 5.x and up ) ,

then we installed application on each Linux So after we have complete machine with Linux + app on each server in the blade HW we intend to clone each of the blade servers ( disk clone )

We already have PXE server so disk cloning will be via PXE server

backup & restore application must be in the PXE server - PXE server is linux machine

There are allot of backup & restore tools as clonezilla or acronics , but what we need is the best Reliability tool

and its must be very friendly user interface GUI , and also free software

Please advice what our options ?

Comment: You should probably accept some answers (or clarify your earlier questions).

Answer (score 0):

g4u comes in mind (it needs a ftp server to store images)
bu one might make some menu in a root image of e.g openbsd install disk (which is able to include root ramdisk inside kernel boot image)